# nextjs import but don't invoke function throws Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns'

Tags: mongodb, npm, next.js, node-mongodb-native

My project(NextJS) was working fine and suddenly I am experiencing the issue `ModuleNotFoundError`. Particularly in the case of dynamic routing of nextJs.

Error I see is: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns'`

In the `pages` directory `pages/programs/[programtype]/[program].jsx` when mongo is imported, it throws:

`ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'node_modules/mongodb/lib'`

Full error dump:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/project-path/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
    at /project-path/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
    at /project-path/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at /project-path/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at /project-path/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at /project-path/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /project-path/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at /project-path/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at /project-path/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
    at /project-path/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/project-path/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /project-path/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /project-path/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/project-path/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /project-path/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/project-path/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at /project-path/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
```

Comment: Give us the code where you call the 'dns' module please

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### The problem

This is a subtle problem with server-side code in Next.js.

The error is *clear* - you're trying to execute server side code (mongo query) in a client side code. But the cause is not *obvious*, because with Next.js *you should be able* to call Mongo from your components.

### The cause

Next.js throws this error because **you are importing your mongo code without using it**.

*It sounds weird but it is true*.

### How to avoid it

To avoid this error just **remove any server-side code `import`** in your components **if you don't use it in `getServerSideProps`**.

*It sounds even more weird but it is true*.

### Good and bad examples

This works fine:

```
import { findUsers } from '../lib/queries'

function Home({ users }) {
  return (
    <h1>Users list</h1>
    //users.map and so on...
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const users = await findUsers()
  return {
    props: {
      users: users
    }
  }
}

export default Home
```

While this will throw the error:

```
import { findUsers } from '../lib/queries'

function Home({ users }) {
  return (
    <h1>Users list</h1>
    //users.map and so on...
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // call disabled to show the error
  // const users = await findUsers()
  return {
    props: {
      users: [] //returning an empty array to avoid other errors
    }
  }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: I've been bitten by this a couple of times. The error messages aren't helpful at all.

Comment: Not Mongo but I had a similar issue that was resolved similarly.

Comment: My problem was I called `getServerSideProps()` as `getServerSiderProps()` ... some days haha

Comment: It doesn't make sense for me. Some files in my `root/lib/` can be used correctly, but some are not. How come?

Answer (score 1):

Keep your server-side coding modules (for e.g: models, database connection maker) outside of the Page directory.

For reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Comment: I had my mongodb class inside utils folder next to pages folder but still got this error. Removing import for the mongodb stuff in index.js helped

Comment: Your solution worked for me. I had my `lib` folder inside `pages` folder. My `lib` folder had dbconnection code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error with Next-js auth, make sure your "lib" folder is in the root directory.

[Here's the structure](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that i used a function in initialprops wich was exported via module.exports instead of export default

Answer (score 0):

I created a directory called 'api-lib' in my project **root directory** to add my **queries** and that caused this error to appear.
And I solved it by moving my  **'api-lib'** directory into the main **'src'** directory.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was exporting `getServerSideProps` with all of it's server side operations from a component, where it should only be placed and exported from a PAGE component.

Moving getServerSideProps to the main page component and just drilling down what I needed to the child component solved it for me.