# Integrating mongodb within existing NextJS(TS) app "Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'"

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I am trying to integrate `mongodb` within my NextTS app but I am having an issue and I can not figure it out.

What I did so far:

I created the two process variables `MONGODB_URI` and `MONGODB_DB`

I created `mongodb.ts` under the `utils` folder, with the following contents that I took from  https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/util/mongodb.js :

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const MONGODB_DB = process.env.MONGODB_DB;

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error("Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local");
}

if (!MONGODB_DB) {
  throw new Error("Please define the MONGODB_DB environment variable inside .env.local");
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongo;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };

    cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((client) => {
      return {
        client,
        db: client.db(MONGODB_DB),
      };
    });
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  return cached.conn;
}
```

Just to try it out, I have tried with the example project (which is just JS), and it is working just fine `yarn create next-app --example with-mongodb with-mongodb-app`

When I start the app, this is where it breaks as far as the log goes:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no custom webpack configuration in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
error - ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/gssapi.js:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'
null
```

And after a save in a file, so that it tries to recompile:

```
wait  - compiling...
info  - Using external babel configuration from C:\Users\Darkbound\Desktop\Inventory-ReactTS\.babelrc
error - ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/gssapi.js:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'
null
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'node\_modules/mongodb/lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739543/modulenotfounderror-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-dns-in-node-modul)

Comment: I did read that post while searching for the solution, but no, at least I could not find such code within my code. I just switched to mongoose, and mongoose worked without issues.

Answer (score -3):

I just ran `npm install dns` as it seems there is a missing dependency in the package.