# How to execute server side code with data from the client in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to get the meta data from a URL the user enters in my Next.js application.

I'm using [metadata-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metadata-scraper) to do this.

At the moment when the user submits the form my application fails with error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'

I did some research and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739543/modulenotfounderror-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-dns-in-node-modul) implies that the issue is because i'm trying submitting server side code on the client, which makes sense. I'm unclear though how I could pass the url the user enters on the page to the server and return the metadata.

Here is my code

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Input from '@/components/ui/Input';
import Button from '@/components/ui/Button';

const tree = () => {
  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

  const handleFindUrl = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const getMetaData = require('metadata-scraper')
    const link = url

    getMetaData(url).then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  };  

  return (
    <section className="bg-black mb-32 mx-auto max-w-6xl px-6">
      <form onSubmit={handleFindUrl} className="flex flex-col space-y-4">
        <Input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Link"
            value={url}
            onChange={setUrl}
            required
            />
            <Button 
                variant="slim" 
                type="submit" 
                loading={loading}>
                Sign up
            </Button>
        </form>
    </section>
  );
}

export default tree;
```

Comment: one thing you can do is use [nookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nookies) package and store the url in cookies,  use an unControlled input and then set useEffect with url as a dependency, then parse the cookies in server side from `getServerSideProps` and use the `getMetadata` function inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying you've many users who put URLs and data from that site will automatically be fetched. But this can't be possible. You can't do this all entirely from the `front-end`.

It's basically happening because You have the script that makes some request to another website and the browser blocks your  **`Cross-Origin`** request to that **website/URL.**. The main reason, a browser blocks this type of request is because of  **`specter security vulnerability`**. Third-party requests to a website could allow an attacker to read what's memory in the client's device. That's why this is not possible.

But **You can do this with `Cloud Functions`**. And use **`useEffect`** or **useFetch** with your API. That's work very fine to get your data .